# iOS local receipt validation with CommonCrypto framework

Tags: ios, iphone, openssl, commoncrypto, receipt-validation

Simple question: Did anyone manage to perform local receipt validation with `CommonCrypto` framework instead of `OpenSSL` and if yes - is there any sample code how to do that?

So, replace all `OpenSSL` related things from Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html) with `CommonCrypto` framework?

Something which looks like solution for `OSX` exists in here https://gist.github.com/sazameki/3026845 but I would like to know if there's anything like that available somewhere for `iOS`.

Thanks in advance for any kind of answer or advice.

Comment: Hi @uerceg, did you ever manage to find a way to use CommonCrypto to validate the receipt for iOS?

Comment: Hi @ChristineLoh. Nope. Still nothing.

Comment: Anyone has more info?